# Redirect link to another Google drive video

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, google-workspace

Is there a way to redirect a link to another video in Google Drive when both are made shareable?

I ask this because I have shared someone a link to an older video and I want them to access the new video even when they click on older link.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to *redirect* links however can use Drive's native version control to get the same result.

1. Right click on the original video file
2. Select *Manage versions...*
3. Click upload new version

Here's that in action

[image: Replace Older Version with New Version]

The URL to that video (file) does not change. In effect people who click the older link will be served the latest version of the file.

*If you want to have both the former and new version available at the same time*, you can make a copy of the older video

[image: Make a copy]

Then replace the original file with a new version

[image: New Version]